# Deserialize method within a class which should be deserialized C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I want to deserialize an object from XML. However I need it to be done from this particular object.
My logic is as follows:

```
[XmlRoot("Data")]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlAttribute("property1")]
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("property1")]
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
    
    public void SerilizeToXML(string filepath) // <------ serialization to XML works fine
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
    }
    
    public void DeserializeFromXML(string filepath) // <------- this does not work
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        this = (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
     }
    
}
```

I need to understand what logic should be in `DeserializeFromXML` method.
Is that possible in general?

Thanks

Comment: "However I need it to be done from this particular object." - what **exactly** do you mean by this? There is absolutely nothing stopping _any program_ written in _any language_ from reading an XML in any particular way... so it sounds like you have an X/Y Problem.

Comment: Can you use a `static` method which returns the object from `(MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(stream)`?

Comment: Why does it have to be specifically from within that same class. Can it not be an extension method or in a static helper class somewhere or even at the point that you need the deserialized data. If you are to insist on having it in that class, maybe you can give us the error that comes out and at which line - we'll be better able to help you then

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize over an existing object; you would need, instead:

```cs
public static MyClass DeserializeFromXML(string filepath)
{
   // ...
   return (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

(probably use `using` rather than `Close`/`Dispose` etc manually)